# How to make a tensor product into matrix?

Tags: matrix, tensors

```
TensorProduct[PauliMatrix[1], DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]] // TableForm
```

created a tensor, which could be flatten to table form.
However, how to make the tensor into a matrix?

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[PauliMatrix[1], DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank! So I need to use ArrayFlatten directly? Why doesn't it work for TableForm?

Comment: `TableForm` like all other commands ending on `Form` such `MatrixForm` are just for displaying purposes. Do not use them in computations.

Answer (score 3):

```
KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], IdentityMatrix[2]]
MatrixForm@%
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$